# Finding coefficients for a loss function with multiple parts and different scales

Tags: machine-learning, loss-functions

I'm working on reusing the paper [Pixel2Mesh++: Multi-View 3D Mesh Generation via Deformation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.01491), which deforms a 3D mesh to make it fit some 2D images, in another scenario than the original one.

The loss function is comprised of four terms : the chamfer loss, the cosine loss, a Laplacian regularization and an edge length regularization ([description here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.01654.pdf)).

These 4 terms have very different scales and are somewhat unbound, meaning that I can't normalize all of them using a maximum value and that if I leave them as-is, some of them will be lost (lol) in the optimization. To add to the problem, not all parts of the loss are equally important : the chamfer loss, minimizing the distance between the expected and actual meshes, should for example have a higher weight in the optimization when compared to the regularization factors.

In the [github repository](https://github.com/walsvid/Pixel2MeshPlusPlus/blob/master/modules/losses.py), some coefficients were found that may or may not be optimal for the problem at hand. I'm guessing they're not bad, considering that's what the authors decided to use. However, the method used to find these coefficients isn't explained anywhere (I even tried opening a github issue regarding this but I didn't get any answer).

Now, I've read many questions here regarding optimization of the questions of multi-loss optimization and loss scaling, but I still don't know how to approach the problem of finding the optimal coefficients.

I thought about using a hyperparameter optimizer like [Hyperband](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.06560) to find the best coefficients, but what obviously happens is that the engine takes the lower bound of each coefficient, leading to a small loss, but not a better result.

I read about using a balance factor like $ \lambda*loss1 + (1 - \lambda)*loss2 $, but I don' think this cannot be applied to more than two losses.

Finally, I tried setting coefficients by myself to get better results, but this looks like an endless search.

So, my question would be : What are ways to find good coefficients for a loss function with multiple parts where not all parts have the same scale?

Comment: You can generalize the "balance factor" to three or more losses by using non-negative $0 \le \lambda_i $ such that $\sum_i \lambda_i=1$. The total loss becomes $L = \sum_i \lambda_i \text{loss}_i$.

Comment: @Sycorax Yes but the advantage of having one balance factor is that you only have one hyperparameter to find. With one coefficient per loss part, I come back to the same problem that finding the best hyper parameters becomes difficult, no?

Comment: It's usually harder to do two (or more) things compared to doing 1 thing, but hyper-parameter is a nearly inevitable part of any machine learning project. Moreover, methods like random search (a very common choice) have a cost that scales only with your *budget* of hyper-parameters to attempt, so in that sense there is no difference in the number of models you estimate: you test $k$ hyper-parameter combinations in either scenario. (You could find quantitatively superior results if you use a larger budget, but that's trivially true.)

Comment: @Sycorax Well I can certainly agree with your assertion. The thing is, I'm looking for ways to scope the grid search to some potentially interesting values. At least looking at the scales of the different losses, it gets complicated quickly. I was wondering if there isn't a way to deal witth his

Comment: When you're tuning a loss function with four different terms, complexity seems inescapable. The range of options has two extremes: make some informed guesses (like using the published results) and accept that your model might be worse than with tuning, or else try lots of different configurations and accept that you'll spend lots of time tuning. There is a middle ground, where you deliberately limit your budget of experiments, and that niche is best filled by random search because it's always trying new values for all parameters (not repeatedly testing bad values like grid search).